# Change the color of a button when it gets clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

This function is working. Every time I press the button it changes from "click me" to "click me again", but I want the button to be blue when it states "click me" and red when it's "click me again".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <button id="toggle" onclick="myFunction()" onclick="setcolor(blue)">click me</button>

        <script>

            function myFunction() {

                var change = document.getElementById("toggle");
                if (change.innerHTML == "click me again"){
                    change.innerHTML = "click me";
                }
                else {
                    change.innerHTML = "click me again";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second onclick listener from the button, then add the coloration code in your `myFunction` function:

```
if (change.innerHTML == "click me again") {
    change.innerHTML = "click me";
    change.style.background='blue'
}
else {
    change.innerHTML = "click me again";
    change.style.background='red'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `backgroundColor` on click just add one click function

```html
<button id="toggle" onclick="myFunction()" >click me</button>

<script>

    function myFunction() {

        var change = document.getElementById("toggle");
        if (change.innerHTML == "click me again")
        {
            change.innerHTML = "click me";
            change.style.backgroundColor = "blue"

        }
        else {
            change.innerHTML = "click me again";
          change.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The first answer helped me but thanks for giving me your time